# Cassandra Backup Strategy: When using local disks

Tags: cassandra, database-backups

We are planning to deploy a Cassandra cluster with 100 virtual nodes. To store maximally 1TB (compressed) data on each node. We're going to use (host-) local SSD disks.

Infrustructure team recommends only using SANs(even for data) since it's easier for them to backup the data.

1. Which of the following methods are recommended?

   - Using more **local disks** for backup
   - Using local disks for data and **SAN** for backup
2. Does the backup process have **overhead** which could slowdown Cassandra's write-heavy workloads?

   - overhead of **copying** the data to the backup disk
   - overhead of transferring data through **network** offsite

Comment: @jersten You can certainly back up data to external storage (SAN or cloud).  DSE opscenter provides that and so does Talena (www.talena-inc.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do your Cassandra backups with `nodetool snaphot`, the backup are only hard links of your data files. And AFAIK Datastax recommends using SSDs for your data files.